# How to query IOS Contacts Contacts Display order settings using New Contact Framework

Tags: ios, swift, contacts

I am developing an app where I am showing some contacts from the server and currently i am sorting the contacts from the server but now i want to read the contact setting from IOS ->Settings ->Contacts ->Display Order using the new Contact framework , I do not see any api to query system settings directly without creating any contact object which I do not want to do I just want to query system settings without creating any contact object.

Im able to query sort settings using below code but there is no equivlent for display order

```
let sortContact = CNContactsUserDefaults.sharedDefaults().sortOrder
```

Comment: What do you mean by creating a contact object? Your code doesn't look like it creates a contact object.

Answer (score 3):

I had run in the exact same issue some days ago and the single solution found was to create a fake contact (note I did not save it in the address book) you can check the code below:

```
let fakeContact = CNContact()
let displayOrder = CNContactFormatter.nameOrderForContact(fakeContact)
print("Display order : \(displayOrder.rawValue)")
```

Comment: +1 This is one of those parts of `Contacts` that baffles me. The value is not settable anywhere in code, which means every CNContact returns the same value... why not just expose it as a global?

Comment: Doesn't work on iOS 12, always gives `givenNameFirst` regardless of the user configuration

Answer (score 2):

In case you are already enumerating over the the contacts you need not create fake contact.  You can use the second line suggested by @user6295172 directly.  Below is one such example from one our projects.

```
public func enumerateContacts() -> Void {
    let contactStore = CNContactStore()
    let filterFields = [CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName), CNContactPhoneNumbersKey] as [Any]
    let fetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: filterFields as! [CNKeyDescriptor])

    do {
        try contactStore.enumerateContacts(with: fetchRequest) { contact, stop in
            if contact.phoneNumbers.count == 0 {
                // No phone number associated with the contact
                // worth skipping it or do what you feel like
            }

            if CNContactFormatter.nameOrder(for: contact).rawValue == 0 {
                print(contact.identifier, " : ", contact.familyName, contact.givenName)
            } else {
                print(contact.identifier, " : ", contact.givenName, contact.familyName)
            }


            for phone in contact.phoneNumbers {
                print(phone.identifier, " : ", phone.value.stringValue)
            }

            print("\n")
        }
    } catch let err {
        print(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's just for displaying the name you can use the `PersonNameComponentsFormatter`:

```
var nameComponents = PersonNameComponents()
nameComponents.givenName = "Mihai"
nameComponents.lastName = "Radu"
print(PersonNameComponentsFormatter.localizedString(from: nameComponents, style: .default, options: []))
```

According to the docs this takes into account the name order rules for the current locale but allows user preferences to override it.